# Include WinPcap in a Python binary

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, winpcap, npcap

I made a Python 3 program that uses Scapy, then I used pyinstaller to generate a binary and it works fine, but there’s always the need to install WinPcap separately to be able to use the binary.

Is there a way to include WinPcap/npcap to the binary, so the user won’t bother installing additional software?

Answer (score 0):

Winpcap isn't just a library. It actually installs a service and copies a few DLLS to `C:/Windows/system32`.

You'll need to install it.

Moreover, the installer doesn't support command line installation :/ the only thing that currently works is the chocolatey package, which uses AutoHotKey and is kinda messy.